# How can I add mp3 audio to an mp4 video?

Tags: audio, windows

I have been sent a video clip from our latest gig, but it was taken on a small camcorder and the bass has overloaded the sound. Luckily I have a studio version at the same speed that I can use.

I don't have budget to use one of the packages I usually recommend, so can I do this on a Windows platform using only free/open source software?

Update (I should have included this earlier) - the audio is not the same length as the video, and it does not start in sync.

I have looked at [Yamb](http://yamb.unite-video.com) but it really only works if everything is synchronised before you start.

(Have seen [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/2419/674), but it doesn't help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use either [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) or [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)(+[Avanti](http://avanti.arrozcru.com/)). Basically, do a video copy and an audio copy and specify the audio source as your studio version. This assumes that your new audio is in sync and of the same length.

Comment: my fault - I'll update the question. The audio is not the same length - nor does it start in sync.

Comment: Both solutions allow you to specify an audio offset. When exporting, the length maintained is that of the video. So longer audio clips are clipped.

Comment: In the end I had to use Yamb to strip the audio from my mp4, as Avidemux kept trying to add the two audio streams together, but then I successfully used avidemux with an offset of -2950ms very successfully.

Comment: And although I got things slightly mistimed - this is how it came out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSP7FTmz7RI